# how to make find correlation for each year?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the correlation for each year in a data frame using `group_by` and `mutate`. When I try to find the correlation coefficient of two different years, I get two different values. When I try to calculate the correlation coefficient for each year all at once, the same value is shown for each year.

Here, the correlation coefficients are different.

```
gm52 <- gapminder %>% filter (year == 1952)
cor(gm52$lifeExp, gm52$gdpPercap, use = "complete.obs")
gm57 <- gapminder %>% filter (year == 1957)
cor(gm57$lifeExp, gm57$gdpPercap, use = "complete.obs")
```

When I try to calculate them all at once, it's the same value in the new data frame

```
gmtest <- gapminder %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(crltn = cor(gmtest$lifeExp, gmtest$gdpPercap, use = "complete.obs"))
```

Comment: Replace `mutate()` with `summarise()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing it in the question, but it seems your main objective is simply to get correlations by year. You dont really have to use `mutate` or `summarise` if you use the `correlation` package (though the other answer here is certainly a good enough option). As a demonstration, I've emulated correlations on the same variables as the last answer:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)
library(correlation)

#### Single Command Correlation ####
gapminder %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  select(lifeExp,
         gdpPercap) %>% 
  correlation()
```

Which gives you similar output:

```
# Correlation Matrix (pearson-method)

Group | Parameter1 | Parameter2 |    r |       95% CI | t(140) |         p
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1952  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.28 | [0.12, 0.42] |   3.42 | < .001***
1957  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.30 | [0.15, 0.45] |   3.77 | < .001***
1962  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.38 | [0.23, 0.52] |   4.91 | < .001***
1967  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.48 | [0.34, 0.60] |   6.48 | < .001***
1972  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.46 | [0.32, 0.58] |   6.12 | < .001***
1977  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.62 | [0.51, 0.71] |   9.35 | < .001***
1982  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.72 | [0.63, 0.79] |  12.37 | < .001***
1987  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.75 | [0.67, 0.81] |  13.41 | < .001***
1992  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.70 | [0.61, 0.78] |  11.75 | < .001***
1997  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.70 | [0.61, 0.78] |  11.72 | < .001***
2002  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.68 | [0.58, 0.76] |  11.03 | < .001***
2007  |    lifeExp |  gdpPercap | 0.68 | [0.58, 0.76] |  10.93 | < .001***

p-value adjustment method: Holm (1979)
Observations: 142
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use [`dplyr::mutate`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html), you are adding a new variable to the existing data frame. As the `gapminder` data is 1704 rows, you will get a vector of length 1704. However, because you have grouped by `year`, there will be only one value per year. This means that the value for each year is [recycled](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-recycling-in-r/) until it is the length of all observations in that year.

Conversely, if you use [`dplyr::summarise`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html), this reduces the length of each group to the length of the output of the function. In this case, the function is `cor()` and the output is one number, so this means one row per year.

Additionally, with `dplyr` you do not need to use dollar notation, e.g. gmtest$lifeExp, and this can break the grouping. It is preferable to omit the name of the data frame and write `lifeExp`.

```r
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)

gapminder |>
  group_by(year) |>
  summarise(
    crltn = cor(lifeExp, gdpPercap, use = "complete.obs")
)
# # A tibble: 12 x 2
#     year crltn
#    <int> <dbl>
#  1  1952 0.278
#  2  1957 0.304
#  3  1962 0.383
#  4  1967 0.480
#  5  1972 0.460
#  6  1977 0.620
#  7  1982 0.723
#  8  1987 0.750
#  9  1992 0.705
# 10  1997 0.704
# 11  2002 0.682
# 12  2007 0.679
```

Comment: I've actually never used a `mutate` or `summarise` function for this purpose before but I think I'll try this in the future.